# 'clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1' 'directory not found for option'

Tags: xcode6, linker-errors, linker-warning

The title says it all; Suddenly my project won't build anymore and I can't figure out why.

Stackoverflow don't allow me to post picture, so here is a link;  https://i.stack.imgur.com/iU9XL.png

This error doesn't tell me much, maybe you know more about it. What I have tried is:

-Removed and added the Parse library

-Removed Derived data

-Removed and added all frameworks

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete and re'add all files in the project, sometimes Xcode mess up and the files won't link to eachother well